# armv6 / armv7 errors when compiling for iPhone

Tags: iphone, compiler-construction

I am having problems trying to compile my App to my iPhone. I upgraded to the new SDK and have 4.0 on my phone... which I did not do that. I am compiling for 3.1.2 - It works fine in the simulator but when I "build" for the Device, it gives me this line of errors:

```
Link /Users/me/Apps/myapp/build/app.build/Debug-iphoneos/app.build/objects-normal/armv7/appname
In /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.3.sdk/user/lib/libz.dylib, missing required architecture armv7 in file
```

then the actual failure occurs on:

```
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After poking around for a while, I found how to fix this problem.

I went into "Project" > "Edit Active Target 'MyProjectName'"'

Scroll down to the "Serch Paths" heading

Double click on the "Library Search Paths" row

This contained a Search Path that said (something like) $(SCROOT)/../iPhone.Simulator/..."

Not sure why that line got in there, but I deleted it.

Then I scrolled up to the top of the same screen and checked the checkbox next to "Architecture" - "Build Active Architecture Only". (I was choosing armv6 but it was building for armv6 and armv7)

Then everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to indicate you are building against the 3.1.3 simulator.  Are you sure you're targeting the device?